# Symfony 4 VichUploader: file can't be removed from the database

Tags: symfony

I am using VichUploader in my application to upload images, it works verry fine but when i try to delete the image, the file is delete from the disk but not from the database it shows this error:

```
Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given at property path "name".
```

the image object dumping is like so:

```
Image {#462 ▼
  -id: 20
  -file: null
  -name: "RehrlwnDcd.jpg"
  -updatedAt: DateTime @1557958944 {#460 ▶}
  -tags: PersistentCollection {#495 ▶}
}
```

and the vich configuration is :

```
inject_on_load: false
delete_on_update: true
delete_on_remove: true
```

when i set the delete_on_remove to false the image is deleted from the database but still in the disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your entity I think in your code you have code like this.

```
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
```

and if it's true you can change

```
getName(): string to getName(): ?string
and setName(string $name) to setName($name)
```

if it's not heled you please show all error message :)

Comment: It works, i changed setName(string $name) to setName(?string $name)

Comment: Salim, you should have a look on [MakerBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html). `The php bin/console make:entity YourEntity --regenerate` command console will help you to generates good getters and setters to avoid this kind of problems.